# Chrome new tab page to beautify and check code

Tags: gratis, chrome, offline, code-beautification, validation

I am looking for a Chrome extension to replace the New Tab Page with one that allows me to paste in some code (in JavaScript, CSS or HTML) and get a beautified output along with any errors if applicable.

Does one exist? It must (as far as possible):

- be free
- run on Chrome as an extension/app
- work offline
- work with JavaScript, CSS and HTML
- beautify the code (i.e. formatted)
- show me errors in the code if applicable, in any format possible (I don't care)

I want this because I need something that's offline and works in Chrome, because I'm in Chrome a lot of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are  a few:

- [jsFiddlePlayer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsfiddle-player/acmoiaipblimhfnjejofmmfjkgpedcpd)

> Opens jsFiddle output to a single unified html page in a new window or tab with one click from the Omnibox.
>   jsFiddle is awesome, but sometimes you want to combine all your HTML, CSS & JS into a single HTML file (perhaps to save it to your local disk). jsFiddle Player does that, it simply adds a "play" button to the Omnibox so that you can pop open a new tab/window with the output combined into a single web page. That's it, simple & useful (at least for me)!

- [Frontest](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/frontest/lkpidflkblcpnhpfdpgiabaadlfddmbd)

> A Chrome extension to try your HTML, CSS, JavaScript code using Chrome DevTool. It's a essencial Frontend Tool

- [Clear Code](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-code/glnikohjhmkofkfcphgbdlmhjdjffcmg)

> Syntax highlighting and beautifiers for embedded code examples.
>   Clear Code allows you to grab any code examples online from blogs, tutorials or forums, and open them in a distraction free viewer.

- [Code Plunker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/code-plunker-live-html-cs/llofhnpelgfcleglkkgfmpfohmlmkofe)

> Rapid front end code testing for developers!, Test your HTML,CSS,JS and Get the program output instantly!